# Understanding the way Javascript deals with object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of JavaScript and the way it handles object and i came across a couple of strange cases that i'm not sure why i'm getting such result.

i am using the console to adding and concatenating objects together(using chrome console):

```
>[]+[]
""
>{}+{}
NaN
>{}+[]
0
>[]+{}
"[object Object]"
```

i would appreciate if somebody have a good explanation for this and/or can recommend farther reading to help me understand reason for this behavior

Comment: look into toString and valueOf, and how cross-type comparisions are made

Comment: A leading `{}`  is always interpreted as a block, not as an object, so your middle two examples are simply `+{}` and `+[]` (an object and an array with a unary plus).

Comment: thanks @apsillers the answer you have pointed is what i am looking for